# Slide java set interval how to repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i repeat my slider.
This is my code so basicly we want to loop the slider.
And maby (if its not to hard) also a execute fuction so it does one time the interval ? like a next button. 
By The Way im new in programming.
Im happy with all your help.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    
    var theImage = $('#product_slider li img');

    var totalWidth = theImage.length * 880;
    $('#product_slider').css({
        width: totalWidth
    });

 if (products.length > 0) {
        setInterval(function () {
            var marginProductSlider = $('#product_slider').css('marginTop');
            var minMargin = '-' + (($('#product_slider li').length - 1) * 880) + 'px';
            var direction = '-';
            if (marginProductSlider === 0) {
                direction = '-';
            }
            if (marginProductSlider === minMargin) {
                direction = '+';
            }

            $('#product_slider').animate({
                marginTop: direction + '=406px'
            }, 1000, function () {
                var curPos = parseInt($('#product_slider').css('marginTop').replace('px', ''));
                var arrayPos = curPos / -406;
                var item = $('#product_slider li').eq(arrayPos).data();
                $('#product_title').text(item.title);
                $('#product_designer').text('Designed by ' + item.designed_by);
                $('#product_description').text(item.description);
            });
        }, 9000);

    }

});
```

Thanks in advance

Manuel

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you are asking for. Can you tell us more? Maybe you could also include the pertinent HTML you are using. A [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) could be helpful.

Comment: Hi, Its a slider and the code above is the javascript of that slider. Now it shows like 8 images and after the 8 images it shows a blank box. I want the slider to repeat the 8 images like a loop.